# how to get a string which have background-color and color different?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to get a string which has background-color and color different?
**Expected output** `BCFE`

**Getting output** :`BCDEF`

```
$(function(){
  //alert()
   var a =''
    $('tr td').map(function(){

      var arr = $(this).attr('style').split('#');
      arr[1] =arr[1].substring(0,arr[1].indexOf(';'))
   if(arr[1]!=arr[2]){
     a+=$(this).text();
   }
      // console.log(arr);
    })
    console.log(a)

})
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #0d71bb;color: #0d71bb">A</td>
        <td style="background-color: #0ea432;color: #0f0f10">B</td>
        <td style="background-color: #e0b4b4;color: #e6a200">C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #FFFF00;color: #FF0">D</td>
        <td style="background-color: #a9d5de;color: #a3c293">E</td>
        <td style="background-color: #b4d95c;color: #b21e1e">F</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

here is my code
https://jsbin.com/vaqifujulo/edit?html,js,console

Explain more

**Show text in the string which is visible**

Comment: Does the order of the output matter (eg: is `BCEF`) fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the styles from your `td` tags in a rather unusual way. I suggest you use jQuery's [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) method to get the colors you're after instead of trying to split the `style` tag:

```
var bgColor = $(this).css('background-color'); // get background color td
var letterColor = $(this).css('color'); // get text color of td
```

Also, note that you don't need to use `.map()`, instead you can use `.each()` to loop over *each* `tr td` element.

See working example below:

```js
$(function() {
  var a = '';
  $('tr td').each(function() {
    var bgColor = $(this).css('background-color');
    var letterColor = $(this).css('color');

    if (bgColor != letterColor) {
      a += $(this).text();
    }
  })
  console.log(a);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #0d71bb;color: #0d71bb">A</td>
    <td style="background-color: #0ea432;color: #0f0f10">B</td>
    <td style="background-color: #e0b4b4;color: #e6a200">C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #FFFF00;color: #FF0">D</td>
    <td style="background-color: #a9d5de;color: #a3c293">E</td>
    <td style="background-color: #b4d95c;color: #b21e1e">F</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert hex color to rgba colors and match them

Answer (score 0):

You can compare `background-color` and `color` property of each element and filter accordingly

```js
function giveStrings() {
  let op = [...document.querySelectorAll('tr td')]
           .filter(ele => ele.style["background-color"] !== ele.style["color"])
           .map(e => e.innerText)
  console.log(op)
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #0d71bb;color: #0d71bb">A</td>
    <td style="background-color: #0ea432;color: #0f0f10">B</td>
    <td style="background-color: #e0b4b4;color: #e6a200">C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #FFFF00;color: #FF0">D</td>
    <td style="background-color: #a9d5de;color: #a3c293">E</td>
    <td style="background-color: #b4d95c;color: #b21e1e">F</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick='giveStrings()'>Clcik me</button>
```